# help in Email templates-How to get record Owner.manager.name

Tags: email-template

I want to send an email template to record owner's manager. So i have to include manager name of record owner's in email like

> Hi xyz,

How can i do that. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As per Salesforce docs there are the only fields which you can direct reference.

> {!ObjectName.OwnerId}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerFullName}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerLastName}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerFirstName}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerEmail}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerPhone}
>
> {!ObjectName.OwnerTitle}

So you might need a Formula field on your object and then use that in your email template.

[Reference: How to include Account Owner's Mobile phone merge field in email templates?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003290&type=1)

Comment: can we do like {!Object.OwnerId.Manager.FirstName}

Comment: @ApexCode I don't think we can.